# Concat two vars to call third var

Tags: bash, variable

I am sorry if this has been answered before, I tried searching and was unable to locate any corresponding answers:

```
$a="hello"
$b="world"

$helloworldtest="worked"
```

`echo "${a}${b}test"` - prints `Hello{World}test`
`echo "${a}$btest"` - prints `Hello`
`echo "$a$btest"` - print `Hello`

Comment: What is your issue? If the value of a variable is to be expanded side by side with another string, the `${...}` syntax for the expansion is required, otherwise the variable name will run into the string (as in `$abtest`) and the shell would no know what you actually meant. As the text of the question does not actually contain a question, I'm not turning this into an answer.

Comment: Please provide an actual question in to your post.

Comment: Of course:  `$helloworldtest="worked"` would emit an error, please correct.

Comment: using
tmp=${hello}${world}test; echo {$!tmp};
should output worked.

Answer (score 0):

use bash's `declare` command to create dynamic variable names:

```bsh
$ a=hello
$ b=world
$ declare "${a}${b}test=worked"
$ printf ">>%s\n" "$a" "$b" "$helloworldtest"
>>hello
>>world
>>worked
```

When you want to actually *use* the dynamic variable name, you have to use:

1. an indirect variable

   ```bsh
   varname=${a}${b}test
   echo "${!varname}"     # => worked
   ```
2. or a nameref (bash version 4.3+)

   ```bsh
   declare -n ref=${a}${b}test
   echo "$ref"            # => worked
   ```

But associative arrays are easier to work with:

```bsh
$ declare -A testvar
$ testvar[$a$b]="this works too"
$ echo "${testvar[helloworld]}"
this works too
```

Comment: Thank you @glenn jackman, this worked perfectly, I used ${!varname}

Comment: Of course, if in bash, a `printf -v $a${b}test 'worked'` would set the value of the dynamic variable as well.